# How to replace exact values for .replace script using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have here a javascript replace script that is activated via `onclick` of a button.

I'm using this to easily replace numbers based on a long list of numbers.

What I'm doing is:

I have this list (please know that this is a sample, there's about a thousand more)

```
.replaceAll("10,", "80,")
.replaceAll("1,", "75,")
.replaceAll("0,", "65,")
.replaceAll("83,", "50,")
```

If I enter **10** in `textarea`, and if I click the "Update button", it should become **80** and not **865** or **7565** since I need an exact value. Right now this is what it's doing, changing **10** to **80** and then the **0** in the **80** into **65**.

I'm looking for a quick or clean way of doing this using RegEx, to maybe add to the script that I only want to change the specified numbers in the quote marks and not those with preceding or following numbers.

Here's my sample code:

```js
function fixTextarea(textarea) {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replaceAll("3d ed", "4th ed")
    .replaceAll("437,", "511,")
    .replaceAll("438,", "512, 517,")
    
    .replaceAll("21,", "24,")
    .replaceAll("309,", "357,")
    .replaceAll("425,", "491,")
    .replaceAll("427,", "493,")
    .replaceAll("430,", "496-502,")
    
    .replaceAll("10,", "80,")
    .replaceAll("1,", "75,")
    .replaceAll("0,", "65,")
    .replaceAll("83,", "50,")

};

function fixtext() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  textarea.select();
  fixTextarea(textarea);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var area = document.getElementById("textarea1");

  var getCount = function(str, search) {
    return str.split(search).length - 1;
  };

  var replace = function(search, replaceWith) {
    if (typeof(search) == "object") {
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      return;
    }
    if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
      var start = area.selectionStart;
      var end = area.selectionEnd;
      var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
      var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
      area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">Witkin & Epstein, Criminal Law (3d ed), Pretrial Proceedings §§ 10, 438,</textarea>

<button class="nbtngreen" onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

I've tried using something like `.replaceAll("/^10,\z/", "80,")` but it doesn't seem to work.

I'd appreciate any help. I'm stuck with this and I really cannot solve it on my own anymore.

Comment: I am not very sure about this approach. You should first replace the values with symbols eg. `replaceAll("10,", "*")
.replaceAll("1,", "@*) .replaceAll("0,", "&") .replaceAll("83,", "+")`. Then in second step, you can replace these with the required value eg. `.replaceAll("*", "80,")
.replaceAll("@,", "75,")
.replaceAll("&", "65,")
.replaceAll("+", "50,")`

Comment: Or another way, if you know RegEx properly, you can do something like putting symbol arround the replaced values and then while replacing other values in the string, replace only when the substring isn't surrounded by the symbol you have used at the first step.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've tried this though, but the problem I run to using this is I will eventually run out of symbols or unique characters for thousand lines of numbers. And then it will again come down to needed to change only the specified value. And you are correct, I'm really hoping for a RegEx line to change only what's inside the quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where you would specify what to replace.

Then you could use a pattern to match 1 or more digits, preceded by a word boundary `\b` to prevent a partial match and assert a comma directly to the right `(?=,)` using a positive lookahead.

In the callback of replace, check if the string exists in the Map. Return the mapped value if it does, else return the original match to leave it unchanged.

Press the button once to do all the replacements.

```
\b\d+(?=,)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/msoKja/1)

For example:

```js
const mapper = new Map();
mapper.set("10", "80");
mapper.set("437", "511");
mapper.set("80", "81");

function fixtext() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replace(
        /\b\d+(?=,)/g,
        m => mapper.has(m) ? mapper.get(m) : m
      );
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">Witkin & Epstein, Criminal Law (3d ed), Pretrial Proceedings §§ 10,438, this should not change 437 and this should: 437,9999</textarea>

<button class="nbtngreen" onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

Comment: Hello this looks like a great solution. But can you please help me by removing the part that where "assert a comma directly to the right (?=,) using a positive lookahead."? The reason for this is sometimes there's no comma, or comma is substituted by a period. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @ixcode If there can be a dot or comma or none, you could use another word boundary like `\b\d+\b` See https://regex101.com/r/zMD8VZ/1

Comment: OMG! This really solved my problems for now! I might have to test it further to find bugs or loopholes. But it's working now as expected. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: One last question please, why does it seem to change only numbers and not letters or how can I change it? for example, "3d ed" to "4th ed" isn't working?

Comment: @ixcode That is because the pattern matches only digits. If you also want to change those values, you would have to make the pattern more specific. Like for example `\b\d+(?:d ed)?\b` Then if you want to list more options, you can use a pipe `|` to add them within the optional group `(?:..|..|..)?`. See a [regex example](https://regex101.com/r/i0G6x3/1) and a [Javascript example](https://jsfiddle.net/ugqfb02o/)